# Как поменять размер Floating Joystick в Unity

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-ui

Всем здравствуйте! Мне нужно менять слайдером размер Floating Joystick из пака https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/input-management/joystick-pack-107631, как это сделать?